# API Design - Purpose of MapItemsControl - why didn't UWP team just use MapControl?

Tags: uwp, api-design, uwp-maps

I was wondering why does the `MapItemsControl` exists?

[image]

Why aren't these right on the `MapControl` instead?

What was the reason why UWP team had put these properties into a separate class instead of adding these right on the `MapControl`?

What's interesting (or confusing?) is you can basically add both `MapItemsControl` and an element to `MapControl` and it displays all:

```
<MapControl>
   <MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
   <Border MapControl.Location="{Binding Location}" />
</MapControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is to enable grouping of related map items. This enables you to take map items from multiple sources and display them. So if you had for example weather data, and traffic data, you would add two `MapItemControl` instances to your `MapControl` and bind the first one to some weather collection and another one to the traffic collection.

Each type of data can also have its own custom `ItemTemplate`, which is also convenient.

Comment: Hmm, so basically it's like having layers? Layers already exist but I guess since they are not MVVM friendly, having separate MapItemControl is the MVVM friendly way?

Comment: Yes, I think this is more MVVM friendly, as you can bind arbitrary data type and provide a custom XAML template which defines how to display it

Comment: Is it correct that if you don't set the ItemTemplate the MapItemControl doesn't display anything?

Comment: I think that is expected. Most controls just show `ToString()` on the item if no template is set, but in case of `MapItemControl` a string would not be very useful either

Comment: It's interesting, there are so many possibilities to add items to MapControl, none give me a way to bind MapControl to an ItemsSource and have the default pins created.